# Leading single quotation mark in every route

Tags: laravel, routes

I do not know what I have gotten wrong in my Laravel application. I am returning Eloquent Model as Json using DataTable from Controller. I keep receiving the error - "Invalid Json response" from the view where I am using the returned Json. Using "JsonLit" I discovered that the returned Json has a prefixed `'` mark - this way:

`'{"draw":0,"recordsTotal":1,"recordsFiltered":1,"data":`

While troubleshooting the problem I created a new route:

```
Route::get("/test",function(){
    return ". . . Something";
});
```

and get the result:

```
'. . . Something
```

In every route there appears the single quotation mark before any other content. It is hardly noticed except in a route that returns a Json response.
Please can anyone help?

Comment: I think this will need deep tracing, as no normal reason to get this single quotation mark. 
You may use help of anyone to have a look with you to use another eye on your code.

Comment: it is entirely possible there is a random `'` before a `<?php` tag or after a `?>` tag (lets hope there are no closing tags in class files) in any php file that is loaded during the course of the request

Comment: @lagbox, Your response was very helpful. I eventually discovered where the single quotation mark is coming from. It was located in web.php, before the <?php opening tag. Removing it, my Json response started working fine. Thanks all.

Answer (score -1):

You have to return a JSON response to get the correct response. Please check the following example.

Ex:

```php
Route::get("/test",function(){
   $users = User::all();
   return response()->json($users);
});
```

Comment: I do return Json response from controller correctly. But the problem is that the single quotation mark: "'"  always gets pre-appended to every response from  every route. The 
 example route above was what made it clear to me that the problem is not with the returned Json,

Comment: @BenjaminEzugwu Can you add your full code to this question? then it will be very easy to find your issue.